# Mayor y menor en una lista Python

Tags: python, array, matriz

Debo realizar un ejercicio, utilizando una matriz, la matriz es la siguiente

```
matriz = [
    [85, 45, 1, 7, 9],
    [12, 52, 9, 151, 56],
    [76, 10, 56, 99, 9],
]
```

Debo hallar el numero mayor y el numero menor, además mostrar en que columna de la matriz se encuentra el numero mayor, y en que columna se encuentra el numero menor, he intentado algunas formas, pero no lo he conseguido.

Comment: Sería bueno mostrar lo que has desarrollado en código hasta ahora.

Comment: Hola @johan-burgos y bienvenido a SO, te recomiendo darle un vistaso a [ask] para conocer un poco más sobre la dínamica de las preguntas, además puedes visitar [tour] para conocer un poco más sobre SO y obtener tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las funciones `max()` y `min()` para saber los valores máximos y mínimos de una lista, además con el método `index()` podemos saber donde se ubica

```py
matriz = [
    [85, 45, 1, 7, 9],
    [12, 52, 9, 151, 56],
    [76, 10, 56, 99, 9],
]

for lista in matriz:
    maximo = max(lista)
    i_max = lista.index(maximo)
    minimo = min(lista)
    i_min = lista.index(minimo)
    print(f"El maxmimo es {maximo} que se encuentra en {i_max}\nEl minimo es {minimo} que se encuentra en la posicion {i_min}\n")
```

**Resultado**

```
El maxmimo es 85 que se encuentra en 0
El minimo es 1 que se encuentra en la posicion 2

El maxmimo es 151 que se encuentra en 3
El minimo es 9 que se encuentra en la posicion 2

El maxmimo es 99 que se encuentra en 3
El minimo es 9 que se encuentra en la posicion 4
```

Si se quiere saber cual es el máximo y mínimo de toda la lista, podemos guardar cada valor obtenido de cada lista y luego sacar el valor máximo y mínimo de esa lista.

```py
maximos = [] #aqui se almacenara el maximo de cada lista
minimos = [] #aqui se almacenara el minimo de cada lista

for lista in matriz:
    maximo = max(lista)
    i_max = lista.index(maximo)
    #agregamos una tupla (numero,indice)
    maximos.append((maximo,i_max))#agregamos a la lista de maximos

    minimo = min(lista)
    i_min = lista.index(minimo)
    #agregamos una tupla (numero,indice)
    minimos.append((minimo,i_min)) #agregamos a la lista de minimos
    
print(max(maximos))
print(min(minimos))
```

**Resultado**

```
(151, 3)
(1, 2)
```

También lo puedes mostrar de una forma *bonita*

Comment: Esto da el min, max de cada columna de la matriz, creo que el man quieres  es el min, max de de toda la matriz

Comment: a bueno tambien se puede, ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: Christian me funciono, gracias! :D

Comment: @johanburgos era eso lo que querias?, iba a agregar como obtener el maximo y el minimo de toda la matriz

Comment: @Christian sipe, aunque lo del mayor y mínimo de toda la matriz también me gustaría verlo para tenerlo en cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar numpy para trabajar con matrices:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import numpy as np

matriz = [
    [85, 45, 1, 7, 9],
    [12, 52, 9, 151, 56],
    [76, 10, 56, 99, 9],
]

l = np.array(matriz)
```

importamos la biblioteca y convertimos la lista en un array

```
pos_mayor = np.where(l==np.max(l))
pos_menor = np.where(l==np.min(l))
```

numpy trae las funciones max(máximo), min(mínimo),where(donde) ésta devuelve una tupla,
ya solo queda mostrar:

```
print(f"""El máximo es {np.max(l)} y está en la fila: {pos_mayor[0]} columna {pos_mayor[1]}
El mínimo es {np.min(l)} y está en la fila: {pos_menor[0]} columna {pos_menor[1]} """)
```

a sugerencia de @Anki Jedi agrego el resultado:

```
El máximo es 151 y está en la fila: [1] columna [3]
El mínimo es 1 y está en la fila: [0] columna [2]
```

Comment: Vale, esta respuesta me gusta jajaja aunque podrías agregar el resultado al ejecutarlo~

Answer (score 0):

Dices que es un ejercicio, por lo que es conveniente que revises las respuestas que te han dado para entenderlas bien. No sé si podrás usar `numpy` u otras cosas más sofisticadas.

Para este tipo de problemas, se puede acudir a la estrategia de aplanar la matriz en una lista de modo que sea más fácil obtener máximos y mínimos:

```py
lista_plana = [(k,i,j) for i,row in enumerate(matriz) for j,k in enumerate(row)]
```

La función [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) da una secuencia de los elementos, junto con un índice de su posición. Aplicándola dos veces, convertimos la matriz en una lista de tuplas:

```py
lst = [(85, 0, 0), (45, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (7, 0, 3), (9, 0, 4), (12, 1, 0)
      ,(52, 1, 1), (9, 1, 2), (151, 1, 3), (56, 1, 4), (76, 2, 0), (10, 2, 1)
      ,(56, 2, 2), (99, 2, 3), (9, 2, 4)]
```

Calcular la posición del máximo y mínimo es trivial:

```py
max(lst)  # --> (151, 1, 3)
min(lst)  # --> (1, 0, 2)
```

Las operaciones `max()` y `min()` son muy rápidas, aunque tengan que recorrer la lista dos veces.

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que no tengas permitido el uso de librerías, podrías hacer esto:

```py
matriz = [
    [85, 45, 1, 7, 9],
    [12, 52, 9, 151, 56],
    [76, 10, 56, 99, 9],
]
```

Inicializar todas las variables con el primer valor que toman, según su posición en la matriz

```py
mayor = matriz[0][0]; coordMayor = [0,0]
menor = matriz[0][0]; coordMenor = [0,0]
```

Luego iterar sobre la matriz e ir comparando nuestras variables con los resultados que vaya arrojando cada iteración

```py
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
        # Encuentra el mayor y sus coordenadas
        if matriz[i][j] > mayor:
            mayor = matriz[i][j]
            coordMayor[0] = i 
            coordMayor[1] = j 
        # Encuentra el menor y sus coordenadas 
        if matriz[i][j] < menor:
            menor = matriz[i][j]
            coordMenor[0] = i 
            coordMenor[1] = j
```

En este caso te devolverá la fila y la columna, pero si solo quieres la columna, simplemente coges el valor que va tomando `j`.

```py
print(f"El número mayor es {mayor} y su coordenada es: {coordMayor}")
print(f"El número menor es {menor} y su coordenada es: {coordMenor}")
```

Y da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
El número mayor es 151 y su coordenada es: [1, 3]
El número menor es 1 y su coordenada es: [0, 2]
```